# stange charaters in dashboard of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding

I have a multi language website and recently my php was updated and I lost the charset definitions. I used to have problems with Portuguese and Russian character too but I solve it with this - 
But my it just solve the problem in the site, the wordpress dashboard continues whit this really strange characters.

Comment: re-copy? No i didn't I just set the DB_CHARSET and DB_COLLATE in config.php and update meta charste in header.php to <meta charset="utf-8" />

Answer (score 0):

You chould update the `DB_CHARSET`and `DB_COLLATE` settings in config.php

This explains the issue pretty well:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: I already have define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); and define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci'); in config.php

Comment: great. And you verified your database is encoded like that?